# Why Apache IoTDB reported `Tablet is empty` when exporting tsfile?

Tags: export, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I am now using Version 1.2.0 of Apache IoTDB, and I tried to execute the export tsfile command in the official guide, `bash ./iotdb-cluster-0/tools/export-tsfile.sh -h ip -p 6661 - u root -pw 'PassWord -q 'select * from root.i.** align by device' -td export-data`. However, the system reported `Tablet is empty` while this tsfile contains data. Has anyone encountered this problem and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When exporting tsfile in Apache IoTDB, you cannot use `align by device` at the same time, and it should be no need to execute these two functions simultaneously. You can try to remove `align by device` and see if you can export all tsfiles.